# Entity framework: Any reason why my related entity isn't "lazy-loaded "?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading

I've an Asp.net MVC website, in which I'm using entity framework in my data store to access the database(with POCO entities).

I don't why but sometimes, it's looks like the lazy loading is just not done:

example of code not working:

```
using(BusinessEntities context = new BusinessEntities()){
   User user = context.Users.First(u=>u.Id == parameterId);
   foreach(Post post in user.Posts){//user.Posts is null here and thrown an exception
      //.. doing some things
   }
}
```

But if I do this, it perfeclty works

```
using(BusinessEntities context = new BusinessEntities()){
   User user = context.Users.Include("Posts").First(u=>u.Id == parameterId);
   foreach(Post post in user.Posts){//user.Posts is null here and thrown an exception
      //.. doing some things
   }
}
```

But I don't understand why the lazy loading doesn't work:

- Context isn't disposed
- It's not a project anonym object or something like that
- I know there is a lot of places in my code where I didn't have to indicate this .Include and doing relative works
- I've the Lazy Loading Enabled set to True on my edmx model

What could leads to this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you are on EF4 and not 3?

Comment: Is `Posts` declared as `virtual`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla : Yes I'm sure, POCO aren't available with EF3

Comment: @Eranga : not but they are "partial", is that a problem?

Comment: @WiktorZychla : Excuse me, I responded to fast, if you mean the property, not it isn't, is this required? I see that some of my properties are

Comment: @WiktorZychla I found this after reading your comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715120(v=vs.103).aspx and now I know that the property has to be virtual! Please post this as answer!

Comment: The comment on virtual properties was from @Eranga. This truly deserves to be the answer.

Comment: My bad, @Eranga could you post a response, like this this I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `Posts` property as `virtual` so that proxy entity created by EF can lazy load the propety.

Answer (score 0):

Please install EF 4.1 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8363 to stop using magic strings inside Include. 
Add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

to your using statements.

Then write the following query:

```
using(BusinessEntities context = new BusinessEntities()){
   var user = context.Users.Include(p=>p.Posts).FirstOrDefault(u=>u.Id == parameterId);
   if(user != null)
   {
      foreach(Post post in user.Posts)
      {
         //.. do something
      }
   }
}
```

For more information refer to the following http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Comment: It's not what I want, specify myself "Include" are working, but the lazy loading should be able to load my "Posts" relation without having to specify the Include(and that, with or without EF 4.1)

Comment: I know i just wanted to tell you that you can omit Include with string and use a generic one. For lazy loading i would not use it as it results in Select N+1 problems in most cases.